# How do the qualitative tests for E.Coli work, which chemicals are used?

Tags: bacteriology

There are test kits that to detect E. Coli in water, by mixing a small sample of water with a certain chemical. After a certain time, the sample changes color depending on the presence of E. Voli above a certain treshold.

How do these tests work and what reagents are used?